# Проверка token в api yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Как в Yii2 сделать кастомную проверку rest api token?
У Yii2 есть 3 стандартных класса

```
QueryParamAuth
HttpBasicAuth
HttpBearerAuth
```

Эти классы делают проверку токена из таблицы User, а мне нужно чтобы происходила не авторизация, а просто проверялся ключ, который я пропишу в params.php.
Есть ли такая возможность?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внимательно читаем документацию
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/rest-authentication

После этого не сильно задумываясь, просто переписываем кусок из примера

```php
class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
        //return static::findOne(['access_token' => $token]);
        return \Yii::$app->params['access_token'] == $token;
    }
}
```

В файле `config/params.php` добавляем параметр

```php
return [
 ...
'access_token' => 'super-puper-security-key',
]
```

Надеюсь это то, что Вы искали :)